# Confusion about regular and $T_1$ spaces

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

I've been reading through Schaum's Outlines *General Topology* and I'm currently looking at regular spaces. The Schaum's books cites the following definition and example:

---

[image]

---

After having read all that, note that the example says that $\{b\}$ is not closed. This must mean that $\{b\}^c$ is not open. Well, granted, it is true that $\{b\}^c=\{a,c\}$ which is not in our topology $\mathcal{T}$. Therefore, $\{a,c\}$ is not open, and thus $\{b\}$ is not closed. But $\{b\}$ isn't given in our topology. I'm not understanding where the author got this singleton $\{b\}$ from. It's not defined in the topology so therefore it shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: $\{b\}$ is just a subset. They are appealing to a property of T1 spaces. If a space is T1, then [all singletons must be closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space#Properties). Since they are exhibiting one singleton that is not closed, then $X$ cannot be T1.

Comment: I understand that all singletons must be closed in a $T_1$ space. What confuses me is that $\{b\}$ is not even defined in our topology. Therefore, it doesn't "exist" in this topology in a certain sense

Comment: Topologies define what subsets are called open, not what subsets exist.

Comment: @plop That just cleared up so much. Thank you! I think that was my problem. It was always my assumption that topologies defined existence as opposed merely defining openness and closedness.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_(mathematics)#Properties) for what entitles $\{b\}$ to exist, due to $X$ being a set and in particular using the [axiom of pairing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_pairing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He mentions $\{b\}$ because a space is $T_1$ iff all subsets of the form $\{x\}$ are closed. And indeed $\{b\}$ is not closed, so that is a counterexample: $X$ is not $T_1$, which is the point.